# Problem with inserting image inside a Table

Tags: tables, includegraphics, nicematrix

I am now preparing for a Final Project of Master's degree and I am facing an issue with Table environement. I have a table made with Microsoft Word showing a list and an image Inside of table.

[image]

I tried so many times to create a table like this one but I couldn't find a way to insert image that fits with the actual size. (4*14)

[image]

Can you please give me an idea or a suggestion on what can I add in the table environement to insert an image with merged rows like the column of "Notations" shown in the first Picture.

My following code is for the second table shown in the second image.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Eléments           & Ration usuel                                                         &  Valeur  \\ \hline
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\
    Hauteur            & $ \frac{L}{25} < h < \frac{L}{20} $      & 230 cm   \\
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\ \hline
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\
    Largeur            & B                                                                    &  900 cm  \\
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\ \hline
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\
    C                  & $\frac{ B}{4}$                                       &  225 cm  \\
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\ \hline
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\
    D                  &  $B - 2C $                                                         &  450 cm  \\
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\ \hline
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\
    $e_{ 1}$      & $ e_{1} \geqslant 16 $ à 18 cm                                         & 20 cm    \\
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\ \hline
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\
    $e_{2}$      &  $\frac{C}{8} \leqslant e_{2} \leqslant \frac{C}{7}$  &  35 cm   \\
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\ \hline
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\
    $e_{ 3}$      &  $ e_{3} > e_{2}$ - 10 cm et  $e_{3} > 1.5 e_{4} $                                &  45 cm   \\
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\ \hline
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\
    $e_{4}$      &  $\frac{D}{30}\leqslant e_{4} \leqslant \frac{D}{25}$  & 25 cm    \\
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\ \hline
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\
    Inclinaison        & $ 10\% \leqslant \beta \leqslant 30\% $                            & $23\%$    \\
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\ \hline
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\
    $E_{a}$      &  $E_{a} \geqslant 0.26 + \frac{L}{500} $                   &  50 cm   \\
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\ \hline
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\
    $ E_{b} $      &  $ E_{p} \geqslant (18 cm, 3\phi , \frac{e_{a}}{3}) $      & 35 cm    \\
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\ \hline
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\
    Gousset supérieur  &  $ 30° < \alpha< 45°$                                                  &  30°     \\
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\ \hline
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\
    Gousset inférieur  &  $ 30° < \alpha < 45° $                                                 &  30°     \\
    ~                  & ~                                                                    & ~        \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `\includegraphics` doesn't need to be in a `{figure}` environment.  You can put it anywhere you want.  That means that the only thing left is how to have a table cell span multiple rows.

Comment: If the answer meets your request please accept it by checking the green tickmark on left side of the answer. Use `\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}` to remove the margins shown in the page.

Answer (score 6):

This approach uses the `nicematrix` package to add and center the image with minimal effort.

The `\Block{nrows-ncolumns}{material}` command behaves like multicolumn\multirow and inserts the material centered in the nrows by ncolumns space (the image in this case).

Additionally, it draws all lines using the `hvlines` key and expands cells vertically with `cell-space-limits`, thus greatly simplifying table code.

[image: g]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,showframe]{geometry}% show the margins    

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr#1-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}}% to center m columns    

\usepackage{nicematrix}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{siunitx}% SI units

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{NiceTabular}{C{0.15\linewidth}C{0.275\linewidth}C{0.125\linewidth} C{0.45\linewidth}}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=6pt ]   
    \RowStyle{\bfseries}Eléments    & Ration usuel                              & Valeur    & Notations \\
    Hauteur             & $ \dfrac{L}{25} < h < \dfrac{L}{20} $                 & \SI{230}{cm}  
    & \Block{13-1}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height =150pt]{example-image}}  \\
    Largeur             & B                                                     & \SI{900}{cm}  &   \\
    C                   & $\dfrac{B}{4}$                                        & \SI{225}{cm}  &   \\
    D                   & $B - 2C $                                             & \SI{450}{cm}  &   \\
    $e_{ 1}$            & $ e_{1} \geqslant 16 $ à \SI{18}{cm}                  & \SI{20}{cm}   &   \\
    $e_{2}$             & $\dfrac{C}{8} \leqslant e_{2} \leqslant \dfrac{C}{7}$ & \SI{35}{cm}   &   \\
    $e_{ 3}$            & $ e_{3} > e_{2}$ -\SI{10}{cm} et  $e_{3} > 1.5 e_{4}$ & \SI{45}{cm}   &   \\
    $e_{4}$             & $\dfrac{D}{30}\leqslant e_{4} \leqslant \dfrac{D}{25}$ & \SI{25}{cm}  &   \\
    Inclinaison         & $\qty{10}{\percent} \leqslant \beta \leqslant \qty{30}{\percent} $ & \qty{23}{\percent}   &   \\
    $E_{a}$             & $E_{a} \geqslant 0.26 + \dfrac{L}{500} $              & \SI{50}{cm}   &   \\
    $ E_{b} $           & $ E_{p} \geqslant (\SI{18}{cm}, 3\phi, \dfrac{e_{a}}{3})$  & \SI{35}{cm}  &   \\
    Gousset supérieur   & $ \ang{30} < \alpha< \ang{45}$                        & \qty{30}{\degree} &   \\
    Gousset inférieur   & $ \ang{30} < \alpha < \ang{45} $                      & \ang{30}          &   \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Use only `\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}` to remove the margins of the page.

[image: z]

Comment: Thank you for your advice and solutions.